# Example of topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

In my notes I read that, given a covering map $p:E\to X$, $E$ is called a $G$-covering if $G=\operatorname{Aut}(E,p)$ and $X=E/G$. Can you make an example of a covering that is not a $G$-covering? Thank you in advance

Comment: A few notes. If I'm not wrong, the correct definition is that $E/G\cong X$ via $p$, not simply that $X=E/G$. Second, there are many examples. This only holds if the orbits of the action of $G$ on $E$ correspond precisely to the fibers of the map $p$. It is possible for multiple orbits of the action to be in a single fiber, in which case the covering is not a $G-$covering.

Comment: An excellent book that covers material that seems to be relevant here is Galois Groups and fundamental groups by Tamas Szamuely.

Comment: @DonThousand can you clarify what the difference would be between $E/G = X$ and $E/G \cong X$ via $p$?

Comment: @RyleeLyman $p$ induces the homeomorphism. It's possible for two spaces to be homeomorphic, but for $p$ to not be a homeomorphism.

Comment: @DonThousand ahhh I see. I think there is an agreement there: the statement $X = E/G$ is stronger than $E/G\cong X$ (abstractly), but if $p$ induces the homeomorphism, then I think expressing that as honest equality is okay.

Comment: @RyleeLyman I was not aware, my bad. Thanks for informing me!

Comment: @DonThousand Actually I thought that multiple orbits of the action couldn't be in a single fiber, because if two automorphisms (say from $E$ to $E'$) send a point of $E$ in the same point of $E'$, then they must be the same automorphism. Can you tell me where I am wrong? Thank you very much

Comment: @Dorian You are correct about the automorphisms. I'm not sure why that means that multiple orbits can't be in the same fiber?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simplest example I am aware of: consider the wedge of two circles $X := S^1\vee S^1$. The basepoint $p$ will be the basepoint of the wedge. Label one of the circles $a$ and the other $b$, and give them an orientation. The cover $E$ will have three lifts of the basepoint, call them $x,y,z$, and six $1$-cells. A label and choice of orientation on the $1$-cells defines a covering map $E \to X$.

Let $E$ have three $1$-cells attached to $x$: one, labeled $a$ is a loop, the other two are labeled $b$ and given opposing orientations and are attached with one side to $x$ and the other to $y$. There will be two more $1$-cells attaching to $y$, each attaching on the other side to $z$. Label these $1$-cells $a$ and give them opposing orientations. Finally, attach a $1$-cell labeled $b$ to $z$ (on both sides). (Draw the picture!!)

It's easy to see that this defines a cover $E \to X$, and that $\operatorname{Aut}(E,p)$ is trivial, so $E$ is not a $G$-cover.

Comment: That's cool!, Here I share a (poorly) sketch in case someone wants to see the pic http://sketchtoy.com/69022451

Comment: Thanks! I love how you sketched the picture to make the covering map clear!

Comment: Why do you say that $\operatorname{Aut}(E,p)$ is trivial? Wrongly, I would have said that it was isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$. Thank you

Comment: @Dorian: If you look at that sketch provided in the first comment, you will see that the fiber over $p$ is $\{x,y,z\}$. But no element of $\text{Aut}(E,p)$ takes $x$ to $y$, because there is an edge mapping to $A$ with both ends at $x$ but there is no edge mapping to $A$ with both endpoints at $y$.